# How to run OS X 10.10 install via command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I am trying to create a script that wipes/partitions the hard drive of old macs and reinstalls OS X so that I do not have to click through the user interface. I can run wipe the disk, but I cannot figure out how to reinstall OS X using only the command line/bash script. Any ideas?

Comment: From my research, it seems like this is not possible.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a 'silent/unattended install'. By the looks of it you'll need to use a deployment tool. This thread should be super useful to you: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/unattended-install.1668132/